# Custom over-the-air (OTA) client application for AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, ota

I want to add a custom OTA application to AOSP Settings placed in `packages/apps/settings` to manage updates in client side. I need to know how I can do this technically. If you know any opensource project or technical example, please refer to them.

I know how it is technically must be done, but I need a few live codes to learn it in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Updater package in Lineage OS project, and found it interesting. Anyone who wants to learn more about embedded OTA packages, is recommended to take a look at this package.

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Updater

It can be easily integrated with AOSP project and has a standard structure of code.